# hadoop-streaming: automate post-processing once job is completed?

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

> Step 1- I have a hadoop streaming job that takes variable time based
>   on amount of data to process   Step 2- Once the job is done, I need to
>   import all that data dump into mongodb and create a flat csv file out
>   of it

**Question**
Is there any way I can glue Step 2 to Step 1 using hadoop streaming and avoid doing Step 2 manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using something like https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob or https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo.  Specifically for mrjob and your problem http://packages.python.org/mrjob/job.html#writing-multi-step-jobs